# redirect from http to https on a node.js server

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu

I'm making a small multiplayer game for the browser using node.js and socket.io. I'm not to familiar with the whole HTTP and HTTPS things.

Currently I'm using a Node.js server for the game on port 3000. With this atempt I am only able to host one server at a time. Either a http or a https server. The problem is, that browser always try to access the http server, but it's insecure.

So my question is: Can I redirect the client to https somehow? Or is there a way to remove the port completly and let it run as a page of my Apache for Ubuntu (Like https://example.com/game)?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing would be to determine if you're in HTTP

Example:

```
const url = new URL('http://example.com')
console.log(url.protocol) // output: "http:"
```

Then to forward to HTTPS, just redirect.

```
res.writeHead(301, { Location: `https://${req?.headers.host}/${path}` });
```

Comment: The problem is, that I am not able to provide both servers on the same port. I can't find a solution to serve http as well as the https on 3000, so one of them is currently getting an error message, that the server denied the request